# Supercritical Van der Waals gas

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, gas

The supercritical regime of a substance is defined as $$\{(p,V)\in\mathbb{R^2} | p\geq p_c \wedge T\geq T_c\} \tag{1} $$ where $(p_c,V_c)$ is the critical point. In figure 1 I added the supercritical regime according to this definition in a Van-der-Waals plot.

During an exam my chemistry professor told me that the Van-der-Waals gas wouldn't be supercritical but be in an ideal gas state in the marked region. While I agree that the behavior can be modeled by the ideal gas equation in this region, I still believe that the substance is in a supercritical and not in a gasous state in this area.

Obviously I didn't want to start a debate about this minor detail during the exam. But can someone give a second opinion on this matter? Maybe it's unusual to speak about supercritical Van-der-Waals gas and the professor just didn't like the term?

[image: Source: The Great Soviet Encyclopedia (1979).]

Source: The Great Soviet Encyclopedia (1979).

Comment: *I still believe that the substance is in a supercritical and not in a gasous state in this area* What characteristic property do you suggest to use to differentiate between the two? This is the only meaningful way one can answer this question (otherwise it's merely semantics).

Comment: What makes you and your professor think that the ideal gas law would be a good approximation within the indicated region.  It seems to me it would be a lousy approximation.  Certainly at the critical point it is a bad approximation. And that bump on the first isotherm above the critical temperature in the figure indicates it is. poor there too.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Well by definition this is the property given by eq. (1). And yes it is semantics in some sense. But I'm still asking because from my examiner I got the impression that it is utterly wrong to talk about the gas as being supercritical.

Comment: @ChetMiller I agree with you. I think it becomes a good approximation for supercritical states of high temperature though...

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum : Suppose I show you a system in a fluid phase. You don't know what it is, and certainly have no idea what its critical pressure and temperature are. Just observing the system, how do you propose to determine whether it is in a gas phase or a supercritical fluid phase? There must be some way, otherwise the distinction is useless. ;)

Comment: How about I lower the pressure at constant temperature. If it is in a liquid phase it will reach a point where there are two phases present at the same time. If it is in a supercritical state this will never happen. @YvanVelenik

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: I want you to make measurements in its current state, not by changing thermodynamic parameters. Otherwise you are not providing me with a property of the phase itself...

Comment: Well without knowing the critical point this will not be possible I fear. @YvanVelenik